# why would I get a "xx not in scope error" for this haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I write such a code, but get an error when compiling saying that "xx is not in scope".

```
test x =
    let xx = 2 * x
     in result 
       where result = replicate xx 3
```

I know I can fix it by using `in replicate xx 3`, however, code above is just a demo, the real code I am dealing with is like below:

```
nthElement :: (Ord b)=>(a->b)->Int->[a]->[a]
nthElement _ _ []  = []
nthElement _ _ [x] = [x]
nthElement op k vals@(x:xs)
    | k > (length vals) = vals
    | otherwise = let left    = [p | p<-vals, (op p) < (op x)]
                      midd    = [p | p<-vals, (op p) == (op x)]
                      right   = [p | p<-vals, (op p) > (op x)]
                      leftLen = length left
                      middLen = length midd
                   in result where result | leftLen >= k             = (nthElement op k left) ++ midd ++ right
                                          | (leftLen + middLen) >= k = left ++ midd ++ right
                                          | otherwise                = left ++ midd ++ nthElement op (k-middLen-leftLen) right
```

It seems that if I don't use the `where` clause, I have to use deeply nested if like this:

```
nthElement :: (Ord b)=>(a->b)->Int->[a]->[a]
nthElement _ _ []  = []
nthElement _ _ [x] = [x]
nthElement op k vals@(x:xs)
    | k > (length vals) = vals
    | otherwise = let left   = [p | p<-vals, (op p) < (op x)]
                      midd   = [p | p<-vals, (op p) == (op x)]
                      right  = [p | p<-vals, (op p) > (op x)]
                      leftLen = length left
                      middLen = length midd
                   in if leftLen >= k 
                         then (nthElement op k left) ++ midd ++ right
                         else if (leftLen + middLen) >= k 
                                then left ++ midd ++ right
                                else left ++ midd ++ nthElement op (k-middLen-leftLen) right
```

So, how could I change my code to fix the compiling bug as well as avoide using nested if?

Comment: Think of it as `{ let xx = 2 * x in result } where { result = replicate xx 3 }`.  The braces show you the scopes.  You could just do `let { xx = 2 * x; result = replicate xx 3 } in result`, it'd be a lot easier to read anyway.

Comment: there is a really good article on the [haskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where) explaining that

Comment: @bheklilr you shoud make it an answer, as it is THE answer to the question (the title at laest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of this code more as

```
test x = {
    let {
        xx = 2 * x
    } in {
        result
    }
} where {
    result = replicate xx 3
}
```

instead of

```
test x = {
    let {
        xx = 2 * x
    } in {
        result where {
            result = replicate xx 3
        }
    }
}
```

The `where` clause covers the entire definition of the function body and can only use names defined outside the function body (which arguments to `test` and `test` itself).  The best way to fix this would be to move all definitions to the `let` or to the `where`.  For your case, you'll probably want to move them all into the `let`:

```
test x =
    let xx = 2 * x
        result = replicate xx 3
    in result
```

Or for your actual use case:

```
nthElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
nthElement _ _ []  = []
nthElement _ _ [x] = [x]
nthElement op k vals@(x:xs)
    | k > (length vals) = vals
    | otherwise = let left    = [p | p<-vals, (op p) < (op x)]
                      midd    = [p | p<-vals, (op p) == (op x)]
                      right   = [p | p<-vals, (op p) > (op x)]
                      leftLen = length left
                      middLen = length midd
                      result | leftLen >= k             = (nthElement op k left) ++ midd ++ right
                             | (leftLen + middLen) >= k = left ++ midd ++ right
                             | otherwise                = left ++ midd ++ nthElement op (k-middLen-leftLen) right
                   in result
```

But, as this marches right off the side of the page, I would refactor it a bit to just use a single guard and a `where`:

```
nthElement :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
nthElement _ _ []  = []
nthElement _ _ [x] = [x]
nthElement op k vals@(x:xs)
    | k > length vals  = vals
    | k <= leftLen     = nth k left ++ midd ++        right
    | k <= leftMiddLen =       left ++ midd ++        right
    | otherwise        =       left ++ midd ++ nth kR right
    where
        opx         = op x
        left        = [p | p <- vals, op p <  opx]
        midd        = [p | p <- vals, op p == opx]
        right       = [p | p <- vals, op p >  opx]
        leftLen     = length left
        middLen     = length midd
        leftMiddLen = leftLen + middLen
        nth         = nthElement op
        kR          = k - leftMiddLen
```

98% of this is just stylistic, you may not like it this way, but I find it a lot easier to read.  In particuarly, I would say that the 2% that isn't just style is collapsing the guards down to a single level, it makes your intentions much more clear.  Since Haskell is lazy you also don't have to worry about computing anything until the value is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

```
nthElement :: (Ord b)=>(a->b)->Int->[a]->[a]
nthElement _ _ []  = []
nthElement _ _ [x] = [x]
nthElement op k vals@(x:xs)
    | k > (length vals) = vals
    | otherwise = let left    = [p | p<-vals, (op p) < (op x)]
                      midd    = [p | p<-vals, (op p) == (op x)]
                      right   = [p | p<-vals, (op p) > (op x)]
                      leftLen = length left
                      middLen = length midd
                      result | leftLen >= k             = (nthElement op k left) ++ midd ++ right
                             | (leftLen + middLen) >= k = left ++ midd ++ right
                             | otherwise                = left ++ midd ++ nthElement op (k-middLen-leftLen) right
                   in result
```